# Migrate a given (old) database to current model

Tags: entity-framework

I am struggling with entity framework's migration quite a bit. Below is how I plan on using migrations, but I find no information on how to accomplish this:

My users are creating databases (Sql Compact Server) on their premises with different versions of my software. Each version introduces a slightly changed EF model. As soon as a user updates to a newer version of the software and opens a database with a previous version of the model, I would like to have some sort of "auto migration" bring the given database up-to-date to the current model.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion database initializer. See this [link](http://www.remondo.net/entity-framework-code-first-migrations-database-initializer/) for more info.